# MVC3 grid split header into many words

Tags: .net, html, asp.net-mvc-3

Perhaps it is a stupid question but anyway...

I have a long word for the column header of **MVC3 Grid**

It is like "skfshkdfjskfjshkdfjhskdjfhskjdf"

```
grid.Column("Details", "skfshkdfjskfjshkdfjhskdjfhskjdf"),
```

So I get a huge column width.

I want to split it somehow into parts 
"sdfsdf"
"sadfsfd"
"sdfsdfsdfsdf"

How I can do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.  I created an extension method to add a space after X number of letters:

```
    public static string AddSpace(this string source, int position)
    {
        if (source != null && source.Length > position)
        {
            source = source.Substring(0, position) + " " + source.Substring(position).AddSpace(position);
        }
        return source;
    }
```

Very hacky, I know, but it worked.

This will add a space after every 10th character:

```
grid.Column("Details", "skfshkdfjskfjshkdfjhskdjfhskjdf".AddSpace(10)),
```

Comment: Sorry Could U explain better where I have to implement it please?

Comment: Thanks! But where I have put  public static string AddSpace(this string source, int position) ?